# Drupal website is broken on localhost

Tags: media, javascript, theming

I have moved a drupal website from live server to localhost.

But the problem I am facing is that everything is broken. no css, no images only text is visible on pages.

On my live website when I click on login button a popup for login appears. But on local host its not working. I have tried using different login URLs but non of them worked for me.

Here is a URL of one image : localhost/sites/default/files/Screen%20Shot%202015-02-24%20at%206.08.54%20PM_0.png

Similarly I have viewed source code of page and here are URLs of CSS and JavaScript files

localhost/sites/default/files/css/css_UCtZrZRD9npGm4D7o8VXPkl5qDJq-m8IlhuR9ccf_tY.css

localhost/sites/default/files/js/js_0gj6QcpfRH2jzTbCQqf7kEkm4MXY0UA_sRhwPc8jC1o.js

These images and files are not found in this location, is this a cache problem ? All these files and images are missing from this location : localhost/sites/default/files

> Note : Most of you are pointing me to following Path :

```
admin/config/media/file-system
```

> Here is what I have

```
Public file system path : sites/default/files
Temporary directory : /mnt/tmp/test
```

> Now should I make both these paths empty ? or change the path ?

Comment: are you on windows? what is your OS?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Please notice you are using two different accounts. That is why it seems to you you cannot edit your own posts.

Comment: kiamlaluno♦ This is only account I have, found this website on google few days ago and registered. I think now my post is edited ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that drupal can't process your files due to not writeable file system paths. 
Go to admin/config/media/file-system and specify public and temporary directories.
After that clear all cache here admin/config/development/performance.

Answer (score 0):

I gust it is because you test it on windows, in windows the directory of temp file is different form Linux
so you just need go to

`admin/config/media/file-system` end empty "Temporary directory " field then save form , and finally clear the cache

Comment: Did you mean on live website I should empty the field of Temporary directory and then take backup of files ?

Comment: no no, just go to `admin/config/media/file-system` and empty  `"Temporary directory " ` field  and save form

Comment: As I asked in my question, on local host I can't login. I have tried using different login URLs but non of them worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely the tmp directory issue. Try configuring `tmp` directory or just remove `/tmp` in `admin->Configuration->media->file-system-> Temporary Directory` and save.

Also, the css and Js files you're pointing are caused because the site has `Aggregate css and Javascript` option enabled. You need to disable `Aggregate CSS and JS`, then do backup. To disable it, `admin->config->performance`